# DHCP letting multiple devices get same IP address - how to trouble shoot?

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp

I am using a win2008 server with AD to also serve DHCP and DNS. I have some wifi AP's that are giving me trouble (dropping connections and generally misbehaving).

The issue that I notice is that the AP's (there are 4) are sharing an IP address (the actual devices are all getting the same IP address) so I can only log into one of them…

I've never seen this kind of problem before and have no idea how to go about trouble shooting…

FWIW they are AeroHive AP's and they are all reaching the Hive manager

More info - my DNS server (and DHCP are at 10.231.0.33 and my gateway is at 10.231.0.254) here is the HORRIBLE tracert results:

```
AH-5482c0#tracert 10.231.0.33
traceroute to 10.231.0.33 (10.231.0.33), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  10.231.20.254 (10.231.20.254)  2.983 ms  2.431 ms  2.819 ms
 2  10.231.0.33 (10.231.0.33)  1.023 ms  4.588 ms  15458.396 ms
```

From another machine in the network (on a different subnet)

```
 $ traceroute 10.231.0.33
traceroute to 10.231.0.33 (10.231.0.33), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  10.231.231.254 (10.231.231.254)  2.322 ms  2.234 ms  2.222 ms
 2  10.231.0.33 (10.231.0.33)  0.331 ms *  0.275 ms
```

so, my hop to the DNS server is very inconsistent...

Comment: That sounds like a failure of both the DHCP server and the DHCP client. The DHCP spec recommends that servers ping the IP address they are about to OFFER, to make sure no one is squatting on it. It similarly recommends that DHCP clients send ARP requests for the IP address they have just been OFFERed, to make sure no one is squatting on it before they REQUEST it. Put a sniffer where it can capture these DHCP transactions, and make sure the AeroHive APs aren't all using the same DHCP Client ID (could be any admin-set string, or their MAC address).

Comment: Are you sure the APs are all "getting" the IP from the DHCP server? Maybe they are mistakenly statically assigned to the same IP?

Comment: @TTT I ended up assigning static IP's to avoid the problem but they are still problematic. I am assuming that the multi-device-same-IP issue is a symptom of a network issue

Comment: Check the MAC Addresses of the APs, some vendor are lazy and do not always increment the MAC of their NIC everytime.  Make sure they're all different

Comment: Also check if DHCP actually leased that IP and to which MAC, you can do that in DHCP console, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Have you check that they don't have duplicate MAC address!!!